# Вернуть два аргумента в Java без использования конструктора

Tags: java, android

Доброе время суток. Столкнулся с проблемой невозможности возвращения двух аргументов. Поиски в интернете на форумах привели к тому, что это возможно только с использованием конструктора. Реально ли решить эту задачу не используя конструктор?

```
public boolean onCheckboxClicked(View view) {
    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.wipped_cream);
    CheckBox checkBoxChocolate = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.Chocolate);

    if (checkBox.isChecked()) {     // checking checkbox status
        checkBox.setChecked(true);
        hasWhippedCream = true;
        return hasWhippedCream;
    }

    if (checkBoxChocolate.isChecked()) {
        checkBoxChocolate.setChecked(true);
        Chocolate = true;
        return Chocolate;
    }

    Chocolate = false;
    hasWhippedCream = false;
    return hasWhippedCream;  //не возможно вернуть 2 аргумента
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Два разных метода определяй. Один который вернет значение checkBoxChocolate, а второй для checkBox! А вообще он void! Вот с оф документации про него написанно:

> 

```
The method you declare in the android:onClick attribute must have a signature exactly as shown above. Specifically, the method must:

    Be public
    Return void
    Define a View as its only parameter (this will be the View that was clicked)

Tip: If you need to change the checkbox state yourself (such as when loading a saved CheckBoxPreference), use the setChecked(boolean) or toggle() method.
```

Comment: Да я через void делал, все получилось. Интересно было почему через boolean не получалось. Спасибо.

Comment: ну потому что он не может быть boolean! это уже особенности языка

Comment: все понял) Спасибо огромное)